# Returning laravel results in the users timezone doesnt reflect correctly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a laravel API, the app timezone is set to `UTC`. MySQL is set to SYSTEM which says it is also UTC, I also have a column on my users table which is the users timezone.

My frontend has a field that a user can enter a date / time for a procedure, this gets sent to the API in the users timezone. So when saving that record, i convert to UTC and then insert into the DB like so;

```php
auth()->user()->procedure()->create([
    'procedure_time' => Carbon::parse($request->procedure_time, auth()->user()->timezone)->setTimezone('UTC'),
]);
```

I am trying to get a record of all the users procedures for the current day in that users timezone, and then return those results to the frontend, I thought i had the right result, but when it hit midnight on my PC, the results were still showing for the previous day for about 10 or so hours AFTER it hit midnight. This is how im trying to return those results;

```php
$todayProcedures = Procedure::query()
    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->whereDate('procedure_time', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->tz($user->timezone))
    ->whereDate('procedure_time', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->tz($user->timezone))
    ->get();
```

I cant figure out where i am going wrong.

Comment: you can use $current_time =  Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Madrid')->toDateTimeString();  timezone change according to your logic

Comment: I think `setTimezone` will just set the timezone and not adjust the time. Is that even necessary? If you pass the carbon instance to the query it should cast it to the correct datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the whereBetween method and pass the converted start and end of the day using the user's timezone. This way, the database will be queried based on the user's local time, and you should get the correct results.

```
$todayProcedures = Procedure::query()
    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->whereBetween('procedure_time', [
        Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->setTimezone($user->timezone)->toDateTimeString(),
        Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->setTimezone($user->timezone)->toDateTimeString(),
    ])
    ->get();
```

When managing timestamps in your application, it's crucial to handle timezone conversions appropriately. To achieve consistency and accuracy, follow these guidelines:

1. Database Storage: Always store timestamps in the database using UTC format. This practice ensures that all timestamps are normalized and independent of any specific timezone.
2. Query Timezone Conversion: Perform timezone conversions at the moment of querying the database, not during record insertion or updates. By doing so, you ensure that the data retrieved from the database remains consistent and accurate regardless of the user's timezone.
3. User-Timezone Based Display: When displaying timestamps to users or processing them based on their timezone preferences, perform the necessary conversions. By adapting the timestamps to the user's timezone, you provide a more user-friendly and localized experience.

By adhering to these practices, your application will maintain accurate timestamp data and provide consistent results across different timezones.

Comment: This didnt work, i think its because im not sending the actual date from of today from the frontend ... Can i change the `now()` to reflect the date sent from the frontend, i.e `2023-07-27` ?? Is that possible?